# Determine for which values for $x\in \mathbb R$ series $\sum _{n=1}^\infty \displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n^x}$ convergent and divergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Determine for which values for $x\in \mathbb R$ series $\sum _{n=1}^\infty \displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n^x}$ convergent and divergent

**My Attempts:** I multiplied numerator and denumerator by conjugate so I obtained $\sum _{n=1}^\infty \displaystyle \frac{1}{n^x .(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}$. Apparently divergence test or n-th term test is useless as limit goes to $0$.

So I was looking for a test that can be useful for it. Actually, I want to compare series with $\sum _{n=1}^\infty \displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$. This series divergent by limit comparison test by series $\frac {1}{n}$. Now using limit comparison test we get $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \displaystyle \frac {1} {n^x}$$
If that limit exists and not equal to $0$ then our original series is divergent. But I believe that it is not possible for any $x$ because limit goes to $0$ for every time.

Moreover, I think ratio test is also useless. Any suggestion is preciated.

Comment: Btw, I tried ratio test and I obrained $\displaystyle ( \frac {n}{n+1})^x $ goes to $1$. It is again useless

Comment: $\lim_{n\to \infty} \displaystyle \frac {1} {n^x}$ is not $0$ for any $x$. Take, for example, $x=0$ or $x=-1$.

Comment: You are certainly right. For $x=-1$ and $x=1$ series is divergent by limit comparison test. However, can we say anything for convergency?

Comment: At $x=-1,$ the series is divergent as you state. But at $x=1,$ the series is convergent!

Comment: The index $i$ appears nowhere in your sum.  If the summand is nonzero, the sum diverges.

Comment: It is my mistake. I should have written $x=0$ instead of $x=1$

Comment: Elementary hint: sandwich $2\sqrt{n}<\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}<2\sqrt{n+1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Hint:

$$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n^x}\;\;\text{is asymptotically equivalent to}\;\;\frac{1}{n^{x+1/2}}$$

That is $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})/n^x}{1/n^{x+1/2}}=1$$

Now Study the convergence of $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^{x+1/2}}$$

Remark: I recently learned this problem from Berkeley Problems book. I just provide the hint from that book.. Mentioning the book may help someone.  Thats all.Credit goes to Paulo Ney de Souza...!

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{1}{n^x(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}\sim
\frac{1}{2n^{x+1/2}}$$
hence the series converges iff
$$x>\frac12.$$

Comment: Is there a good reason for the downvote, or is it again from my serial downvoter?

Comment: I didn't downvote and couldn't get how you obtain second part. Could you explain little bit more?

Comment: There is a misprint: should be $2n^{x+1/2}$ in the denominator. @AnneBauval : I swear I am not your personal downvoter.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Many thanks! (I was on my phone...) I correct immediately. And sure, no need to swear ;-)

Comment: @FuatRay That was just a misprint indeed. Note my factor $2,$ missing in the (subsequent and quite similar) accepted answer, but not very important.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply and divide by $\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}$, to have:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^x\cdot (\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}$$
Now, use the comparison test with $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^p}$ which converges for $p>1$. We have also $$\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}\,\,\sim\,\, 2\sqrt{n}$$ for $n\to +\infty$. So the region of convergence is:
$$p=x+\frac{1}{2}>1\implies x>\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use [p-series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#p-series_test) on the $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n,$ where $$a_n=\frac{1}{n^x(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}$$

See that, by limit by comparision test, $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges if and only if $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ converges, where $$b_n=\frac{1}{n^{x+\frac{1}{2}}}.$$
Now, by p-series test, $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ converges if $x+\frac{1}{2}>1.$ So, for the convergence of $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n,$ we need $x>\frac{1}{2}.$

Comment: Divergence test says that if limit is not $0$ then series is divergent. But limit of $a_n$ is $0$. Test must be useless!

Comment: The $p$-series test is specifically for $a_n = \frac{1}{n^p}$

Comment: $p$ is just a place holder. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, $p$ is a placeholder, but $a_n=\frac{1}{n^x(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}$ is not of the form $\frac{1}{n^p}$ for any $p$.

Comment: Agreed. $a_n$ is not of the form $\frac{1}{n^p}$ for any $p.$ But, it has the same behaviour as $\frac{1}{n^p},$ for $p=x+\frac{1}{2},$ as $n \rightarrow \infty.$